# Generate objectID client side to be save into db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Like my blog system, each post it can have media files. To retain good UX, I want the user to upload their images of a post and save a post.

But I need the id to name my files like /filename.jpg, how can I generate the id using mongodb on client side which it won't clash with the id generated on the server (nodejs) also.

Comment: Generally you can't, but you can make an ajax call to the server that **returns** an objectID, and then use that in your request with the files, however this makes little sense, as what you should do is just send the image, and not worry about the objectID on the clientside at all, just keep a reference in the post as to what images it has etc.

Comment: @adeneo how can i retrieve the image later if I don't put id in the filename? I have to upload the image before I store the name to the db.

Comment: just send the image? send to server with no reference?